# Will the 73017 timing chain from SBC fit a 1995 chevy 4.3 vortec

Tags: chevrolet

Will the 73017 timing chain from small block Chevy fit a 1995 Chevy 4.3 vortec

Comment: Check with a caliper, the width, pitch etc.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the center distance from your cam to crankshaft. The standard SBC distance is 4.521". For your 4.3, it could be 4.511", 4.516", or 4.521". If your V6 is 4.521" from crank to cam, **DOES NOT** have a balance shaft, and **DOES NOT** come with a roller cam (flat tappet instead), this timing chain should work.